# Location based Role authentication not working

Tags: c#, web-config, authorization, asp.net-membership, asp.net-roles

I am working on a web application with sql membership providers.
I have mapped roles for the user in the SQL and the users are assigned to roles correctly.
Following code works fine.

```
        protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        if (Membership.ValidateUser(txtUserName.Text, txtPassWord.Text))
        {
            if (Roles.IsUserInRole(txtUserName.Text, "admin"))
            Response.Redirect("~/Users/ViewUsers.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            lblErrorMessage.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

But I want to do all the access denial logic in my config.
The following code doesnt work. Users with all roles get redirected in spite of their roles.

```
<location path="Users">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow roles="admin"/>
    <deny roles="user"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Kindly let me know what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `<deny users="*"/>` instead. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8aeskccd(v=vs.85).aspx) article with example.

Answer (score 0):

have you try this? it will work

```
 [Authorize(Roles = "Super Admin,Business Admin")]
```

Comment: Where should I add this ?

Comment: you can put it before getmethod or before controller class according to your requirement

Comment: It's `asp.net`, not `asp.net mvc` there is no controllers.

Answer (score 0):

I had to set the formauthentication cookie to do this and all works fine now

```
string username = UsernameTB.Text;
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, false);
```